# When ring is commutative, prove that left and right modules coincide

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I have the following definition of a left $R$-module for a ring $R$ and an abelian group $X$:

these conditions must be satisfied:

$$(\alpha+\beta)x = \alpha x + \beta x$$
$$\alpha(x+y) = \alpha x + \alpha y$$
$$\alpha(\beta x) = (\alpha\beta)x$$
$$1x = x$$

The book then asks me to define a right $R$-module and prove that, when the ring $R$ is commutative, both definitions coincide. That's what I did:

Definition for the right $R$-module:

$$x(\alpha+\beta) = x\alpha + x\beta$$

$$(x+y)\alpha = x\alpha + x\beta$$

$$(x\beta)\alpha = x(\beta\alpha)$$

$$x1 = x$$

I think now I need to prove that

$$(\alpha+\beta)x = x(\alpha + \beta)$$
$$\alpha(x+y) = (x+y)\alpha$$
$$\alpha(\beta x) = (x\alpha)\beta$$
$$1x = x1$$

at least for the last two:

$$\alpha(\beta x) = (\alpha\beta)x = (\beta\alpha)x = \beta(\alpha x)$$

but how to prove that $\alpha x = x\alpha$?

And for the unit it's easy:

$$1x = x = x1$$

but what about the first two?

Comment: This is probably just a question of understanding the definition. What is the underlying set of the module, and how does $R$ act on it?

Comment: @Couchy311 R act on it by multpliying. I know, for example, that for the integers ring, multiplying is just repeated adition, but what about other rings?

Comment: You're going about this the wrong way. It doesn't make sense to say $\alpha x=x\alpha$ because you don't know how these are defined. What you do is you assume you have a left module structure and prove that it can also be realized as a right module structure, where you actually define the right module action rather than assuming it already exists. The obvious choice is to define $x\alpha =\alpha x$. Where could this definition possibly go wrong? The only place is in $\alpha(\beta x)=(\alpha\beta)x$. But that's no problem because...

Comment: You also have to go from right module to left module.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The result you want to prove follows immediately from this proposition:

**Proposition:** Let $(X,+)$ be an abelian group. Then $X$ is a right $R$-module if only if $X$ is a left $R^{\text{op}}$-module. Here $R^{\text{op}}$ is the opposite ring of $R$, i.e., in this ring the multiplication is defined in the following way: $a\cdot_{\text{op}}b=b\cdot a$.

*Proof:* $\Longrightarrow$) Let $\sigma$ be the right action. Since $X$ is a right $R$-module we have $\sigma(x,\alpha)=x\cdot \alpha$, and then the axioms that define $X$ as a right $R$-module can be written in this form: $$\sigma(x+y,\alpha)=\sigma(x,\alpha)+\sigma(y,\alpha),$$ $$\sigma(x,\alpha+\beta)=\sigma(x,\alpha)+\sigma(x,\beta),$$ $$\sigma(x,(\beta\cdot\alpha))=\sigma(\sigma(x,\beta),\alpha).$$

Now we define the application $\sigma'\colon R^{\text{op}}\times X\rightarrow X$ given by $(\alpha,x)\mapsto \sigma'(\alpha,x)=\sigma(x,\alpha)$. So we have to prove that $\sigma'$ is a left action.  Let $\alpha, \beta\in R^{\text{op}}$ and $x,y\in X$. Then $$\sigma'(\alpha,x+y)=\sigma(x+y,\alpha)=\sigma(x,\alpha)+\sigma(y,\alpha)=\sigma'(\alpha,x)+\sigma'(\alpha,y),$$ $$\sigma'(\alpha+\beta,x)=\sigma(x,\alpha+\beta)=\sigma(x,\alpha)+\sigma(x,\beta)=\sigma'(\alpha,x)+\sigma'(\beta,x),$$ $$\sigma'((\alpha\cdot_{\text{op}}\beta),x)=\sigma'((\beta\cdot\alpha),x)=\sigma(x, (\beta\cdot\alpha))=\sigma(\sigma(x,\beta),\alpha)=$$
$$=\sigma(\sigma'(\beta,x),\alpha)=\sigma'(\alpha,\sigma'(\beta,x)).$$

Finally, as $\sigma'(1_R,x)=\sigma(x,1_R)=x$, we deduce that $X$ is a left $R^{\text{op}}$-module.

$\Longleftarrow$) The proof is completely analogous.

Comment: I didn't see what you did, you just called $\sigma$ a different name and played with the equalities

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs did you read what Matt Samuel commented? You have to define your right module action using your left module action. Well, in this case I defined the left action using the right one. Besides, I used $\sigma$ to avoid confusions while performing the operations to show the equalities.