# If $R$ is commutative, the left $R-$module can be given the structure of right $R-$module.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

The definition of the module is given in Hungerford's Algebra by:

[image]

And I can not understand the following paragraph, could anyone explain this for me please especially why commutativity is needed for (iii)?
Thanks!!

[image]

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2203324/29335 too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $A$ is a left $R$-module, where $R$ is commutative.  To make $A$ a right $R$-module under the stated action, (iii) demands we check
$$
a(sr) = (as)r
$$
for $a \in A$ and $r, s \in R$.  This says that, as phrased in the left action,
$$
(sr)a = r(sa).
$$
Since $A$ is a left $R$-module, we certainly have $(rs)a=r(sa)$.  Thus we need to commute $sr=rs$ to save the day.